# mysql database error : call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a mysql table using php

I have the following function to create the table

```
class dbActions{
public $connection;
function dbConnect(){
    $dbname = 'kilimokenya';
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbuser = 'root';

    $connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if($connection ->connect_errno) echo ($connection ->connect_error());
}

function createCustomerTbl(){
    GLOBAL $connection;
    $CustomerTbl = "CREATE TABLE customers_tbl(
        customer_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        emailAddress VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        phone_number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        dateRegistered TIMESTAMP
        )";
    $check = $connection ->query($CustomerTbl);
    if(!$check)
        echo "Customer table not created because ".$connection ->error;
    return true;
}
```

I call the function here :

```
$dbObject = new dbActions();
$dbObject ->dbconnect();

$dbObject ->createCustomerTbl();
```

I get the following error when i run the code: 
     Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\current\kilimokenyafoods\common\server.php on line 31

What im i missing?

Comment: to access a member of an object, you have to use `$this->connection` instead of `$connection`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann you mean: $this ->connection ->query($customerTbl); ?

Comment: still generates the same error

Comment: Change your `$connection` to private, remove the `GLOBAL $connection;` in your `createCustomerTbl()` method, and use $this->connection everywhere. Also consider switching to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: @krimaeus that solved it. Thanks

Comment: Since that actually solved your problem, I'll post it as the answer and you can mark it as solved. EDIT: Guess not, but RamRaider's answer is also fine.

Comment: @krimaeus Alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$connection` property should be accessed within the class using `$this` rather than declaring as a global variable.

The above could be rewritten a little to follow the singleton pattern to ensure that only one instance of the class is initialised  for your scripts

```
class dbAction{

    private static $instance=false;
    private $connection;

    private function __construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname){
        $this->connection=new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    }
    public static function initialise($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname){
        if( !self::$instance ) self::$instance=new dbAction( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname );
        return self::$instance;
    }


    public function createCustomerTbl(){
        $sql='CREATE TABLE customers_tbl(
            customer_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            emailAddress VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            phone_number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
            dateRegistered TIMESTAMP)';
        $res = $this->connection->query( $sql );
        if( !$res )printf( 'Customer table not created because : %s', $this->connection->error );
        return $res;
    }
}



$dbo=dbAction::initialise( 'localhost', 'root', 'xxx', 'kilimokenya' );
$status=$dbo->createCustomerTbl();

echo $status ? 'good' : 'bad';
```

Comment: Change it to use prepared statements and it'll be perfect.

Comment: that query doesn't need a prepared statement though but in general i'd agree that one ought to use them

Comment: You're right. I totally skipped what the query does and my reflex kicked in.